# How can I avoid executing a whole failing test and relaunch it from a specific point instead?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, junit5

Using **selenium grid** and **JUnit5**, I am executing tests that are way too long. Some of them may take about 30 minutes to complete. Maybe, what is failing is a silly locator, which I can easily fix in a few seconds. Then, in order to keep testing and check that the change has actually fixed the failure, I have to retest it again from the absolute beginning. So, **is there a way to avoid this and to retake the test from a specific point?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: The biggest blocker to achieve this is related to the system state.  Most of the tests modify the state during the steps so its not really easy to skip them. The best solution is to refactor the tests(make them fast). To make the things less painful you can run the tests in headless mode so that you can do something else while the test is running. For certain tests may be you can comment the part you know is working.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible.
Also, generally, tests should not be too long and too complex.
Making tests long and complex making the debugging and failures analysis much more complex.

Comment: Okay, I'll bare that in mind... Thanks @Prophet. It would be great to have the option of doing so anyway